# Sub-menus not displaying

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

In wordpress, I create new menu and after I preview all the sub-menus are not displaying What's wrong with menus? Here's the [site](http://goo.gl/49elyC)

And here's the list of menus

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu is there but hidden,
I would remove the .main-navigation ul { overflow: hidden; } rule and change the #masthead overflow rule from auto to visible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the answer is that your theme don't show drop down menus and you don't have any plugin that adds this functionality.

There is a lot of free and premium plugins that can do this, for example this one (first google result):
https://wordpress.org/plugins/dropdown-menu-widget/

If you would like to make your theme capable of showing drop-down menu it is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: the theme that I'm using have dropdown menu, I'm using that in another site and the dropdown is displaying. But I'm wondering why in the dropdown in new site is not working hmm